# Impyla - User does not have privileges to execute 'SELECT'

Tags: python, kerberos, impala, impyla

I am trying to connect to impala using Python (Impyla). I am able to connect, however, I always get an error message saying the user is not able to execute queries (i.e. `User 'ABC' does not have privileges to execute 'SELECT'`. The user shown in the error is the user running the script (for example `'ABC'`, even if I specify a different user in the `connect` and `cursor` statements:

```
conn = connect(host='____', port=21050, auth_mechanism='GSSAPI', use_ssl=True, user='DEF')
cur = conn.cursor(user='DEF')
```

Is there any way to get it to use user `DEF` rather than user `ABC`? I have confirmed that `user` is set to `DEF` by putting in some `print` statements in 'hiveserver2.py' file.